# Web3js signTransation

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I am following the documentation to be able to sign and send a transaction on the Kovan testnet. I am currently getting an undefined value when I console out the txHash.

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (err, txCount) => {
    // 1)Build Transaction
    const txObject = {
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
        to: account2,
        value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.05', 'ether')),
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(2100),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei'))
    }
    
     // 2)Sign Transaction
    const tx = new Tx(txObject,{'chain':42})
    tx.sign(privateKey1)
    
    const serializedTransaction = tx.serialize()
    const raw = '0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex')

    console.log("raw:", raw)
    console.log("tx:", serializedTransaction)

    // 3)Broadcast Transaction
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err, txHash) =>{
        console.log('txHash:', txHash)
    })
    // COMMENTED-OUT web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTransaction .toString('hex'))
    // .on('receipt', console.log);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`signTransaction()` only performs the signature. It doesn't broadcast the (signed) transaction to the network.

For that, you can use `sendSignedTransaction()` ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction)), which submits the (signed and serialized) tx data to the provider, and the provider broadcasts it to the network.

```
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction)
.on('receipt', console.log);
```

Comment: I updated my code and now getting undefined any ideas?

Comment: @PythonCoder1981 On which part are you getting `undefined`? Is the `err` in `sendSignedTransaction` callback returning any non-null value?

Comment: In the sendSignTransaction in the console.log in the output it says txHash: undefined

Comment: @PythonCoder1981 Then it's probably returning a value in the `err` variable, and it didn't set the `txHash`. (In JS, `undefined` value is used for variables that haven't been set a value.) Can you check the `err` value?

Comment: Thanks I figured it out after console.log the "err", the gas limit was set incorrectly I had it at 2100 and changed it to 21000 and it worked.